# HIBERNATE : NotUniqueObjectException after insert new autoicnremnteID object

Tags: hibernate

I have an sql table with autoincremt Id (int)
Inside a a method of a JSF bean when i insert a new record:
I create a new object p=new Prop(); then set all the propieties except the id, and the i submit to the session: session.save(p); 
This works for the first record;
when insert a second or more record i have the NotUniqueObjectException also if i have created a new object;
How can I avoid this ?

Comment: have you set the id generation strategy in hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the id generation strategy in hibernate

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Comment: It still doesn't work; Now i can see that works only with the first record because it creates an object with id=0, an write it in the dbase; and every time that i create a new object it creates it again with id=0, an so i can't write new records...

Comment: Now it is:
    @Id
    @Column(name="cod", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
     private int cod;

Comment: The mapping file is :                                           <class name="util1.Prenot" table="prenot" catalog="gestcars">
        <id name="cod" type="int">
            <column name="cod" />                                                                  
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>                                                                                                                                             I'm using tomcat, and mysql;

Comment: see the example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/KeyIntAutoIncrement.htm

Answer (score 0):

As you are using hibernate, In hibernate we have to define auto increment type
if you are using hbm mapping then do the below one.

for hbm mapping:

```
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
```

for annotation :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: Now I have used :

<generator class="increment" /

and

@Id @Column(name="codice", unique=true, nullable=false) @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO) private int cod;                                                                  and it works;                                                                    Tank you to everybody;                                     (now I must understand better how/why it works , but it is an other prolem...)

Comment: post it in answer and except it yourself